# Defining split condition for a string to be parsed to a dictionary

Tags: c#, string, dictionary, mapping

I seem to have some problems with defining a split condition for  a string. 
The condition has to be used to map the string to a a dictionary.

In a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51050911/extract-properties-from-a-string-given-a-key)

I had a similar issue, but the solution given there might work for that specific case, but is not a solid solution.

It would not work for a text like this:

```
da:,en:H a full-bodied, vinous  wine, which attracts wine connoisseurs with its well-balanced and lively bouquet. It combines crisp  with a rich taste and long-lasting finish. Wines from one single vintage form the basis of this exceptional  wine. som – sparkling since 1856,fr:,nl:,ru:
```

As the text within the language tag has commmas, and can't thereafter select `:`.

Any suggestions to a more solid solution. 
My intention with this is to map the string such that i can get the information, I am seeking given the language tag.

Comment: I am not sure i understand why you have a dictionary with the all language codes.. 
How would you use that to split?,  how would i parse a list of string as split condition?

Comment: no.. it will be a two letter acro

Comment: you need to store the language accro because that what you are looking for. First your string was a simple string with nothing special. Now it has comma had it's an issue for the old solution. How many time for it to have ":"? Will your string never contain somethink like "en:from:UK with the reference Fen:13245", and do you have to handle that ? The issue is you provide only one line exemple with no clear edge case scenario. So I gave you from the top of my head some kind of solution.

Comment: You were right.. It just caused an error due to an : in the middle of the string..

Comment: There is no bullet proof method, thats why we need to define what are the edge case and what we will handle. Especially for free string like this. I will consider using Json, csv or anything that can serialise those data into a bullet proof format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using *regular expressions*; providing that

1. Language is two (small) letter word followed by column: `ru:`, `en:`
2. Comma `,` is a separator: `en: bla-bla-bla,ru: bla-bla-bla`

You can put

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

string source = @"da:,en: H a full - bodied, vinous wine, which attracts wine connoisseurs with its well-balanced and lively bouquet.It combines crisp with a rich taste and long-lasting finish.Wines from one single vintage form the basis of this exceptional wine. som – sparkling since 1856,fr:,nl:,ru:";

Dictionary<string, string> result = Regex
  .Matches(source, @"(?<lang>[a-z]{2}:)(?<value>.*?)(?=\,[a-z]{2}:|$)")
  .OfType<Match>()
  .ToDictionary(match => match.Groups["lang"].Value.TrimEnd(':'),
                match => match.Groups["value"].Value);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result
  .Select(pair => $"language: {pair.Key}; text: {pair.Value}")));
```

Outcome:

```
language: da; text: 
language: en; text:  H a full - bodied, vinous wine, which attracts wine connoisseurs with its well-balanced and lively bouquet.It combines crisp with a rich taste and long-lasting finish.Wines from one single vintage form the basis of this exceptional wine. som – sparkling since 1856
language: fr; text: 
language: nl; text: 
language: ru; text:
```

Comment: is the key here `en:` or `en`

Comment: @famle: the key is `en`